# Cannot connect to one room

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

The room settings are the same, why every time when there is already a created room, the player does not connect there, and creates a new one? I get this warning: Operation failed: OperationResponse 225: ReturnCode: 32760 (No match found). Parameters: {}

```
public void StartMatchMaking(){
    Debug.LogError(CreateRoomProperties());
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom(CreateRoomProperties(), 4);
}

ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable CreateRoomProperties()
{
    return new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable
    {
        {"bet", bet}
    };
}

private void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed(object[] codeAndMsg)
{
    CreateRoom();
}

public void CreateRoom(){
    ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable ht = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
    RoomOptions ro = new RoomOptions();
    ht.Add("bet", bet);
    ro.CustomRoomProperties = ht;
    Debug.LogError(ro.CustomRoomProperties);
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(""+PhotonNetwork.player.NickName, ro, TypedLobby.Default);
}

void OnPhotonPlayerConnected(PhotonPlayer otherPlayer)
{
    Debug.Log("New player: " + otherPlayer.NickName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add properties to roomsettings

```
customRoomPropertiesForLobby = CreateRoomPropertiesForLobby();
string[] CreateRoomPropertiesForLobby()
{
    return new string[]
    {
        "bet"
    };
}
```